# How to remove error “Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2”

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Work on **vs2012 C# ef**.My bellow linq syntax show me error ,if I add **AsEnumerable()** then it’s work fine but it’s make query slow,slow **means much slow**.What to do.How to avoid this error

```
var query = (
                    from bm in this.Context.BilBillMasters

                        join g in
                            (
                                from c in this.Context.BilBillDetails
                                group c by new { c.BillID }
                            )
                        on bm.BillID equals (g == null ? 0 : g.Key.BillID) into bDG
                        from billDetailGroup in bDG.DefaultIfEmpty()


                        where bm.IsDeleted == false
                        && (companyID == 0 || bm.CompanyID == companyID)
                        && (userID == 0 || bm.CustomerID == userID)
                        select new
                        {
                            bm.BillID,
                            BillNo = bm.CustomCode,
                            bm.BillDate,
                            BillMonth = bm.MonthFrom,
                            TransactionTypeID = bm.TransactionTypeID ?? 0,
                            CustomerID = bm.CustomerID,
                            Total = billDetailGroup.Sum(p => p.Amount),


                            bm.ReferenceID,
                            bm.ReferenceTypeID

                        }
                        );

                return query.OrderByDescending(e => e.BillID);
```

error message
[image]

If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advanced.Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `g == null`? It shouldn't be needed by the EF query builder, and it might be a source of confusion to it.

Comment: Luaan thanks for reply, there is no null in g.Suppose there is one group for null ,after used the .AsEnumerable() how it's solve.

Answer (score 1):

You create anonymous class that has no comparator:

```
group c by new { c.BillID }
```

Instead try

```
group c by c.BillID
```

Comment: `bool b = new { a = 1 }.Equals(new { a = 1 });`

Comment: semao,thanks for reply. after used new syntax .problem is remaining     join g in
                             (
                                 from c in this.Context.BilBillDetails
                                 group c by c.BillID//new { c.BillID }
                             )
                         on bm.BillID equals (g == null ? 0 : g.ToLong()) into bDG
                         from billDetailGroup in bDG.DefaultIfEmpty()